# While loop incorrect

Tags: python

the purpose of this file is to ask the user for values, calculates the values for different purposes, and then display data.

Everything works besides the while loop. It is supposed to make the value of servings go down if the Grand_Weight_Mix_Total is > 450.

The while loops checks to see if Grand_Weight_Mix_Total is above 450, if it is, then the value of servings should go down 1 and then the while loop is executed again. The loop will break once the value of servings is below 450.

```
    customerName = input("Customer Name:\n")
mixName = input("Mix Name:\n") 
L_Citrulline_Mallate = int(input("Amount of L-Citrulline Malate (2:1) per serving(grams):\n"))
Beta_Alanine = int(input("Amount of Beta Alanine per serving(grams):\n"))
Caffeine_Anhydrous = float(input("Amount of Caffeine Anhydrous per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000
Betaine_Anhydrous = int(input("Amount of Betaine Anhydrous per serving(grams):\n"))
Taurine = int(input("Amount of Taurine per serving(grams):\n"))
Creatine_HCL = int(input("Amount of Creatine_HCL per serving(grams):\n"))
L_Theanine = float(input("Amount of L-Theanine per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000
L_Tyrosine = int(input("Amount of L-Tyrosine per serving(grams):\n"))
Sodium_Bicarbonate = float(input("Amount of Sodium_Bicarbonate per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000

servings = 35
#Mix Total
Mix_Total = float(L_Citrulline_Mallate + Beta_Alanine + Caffeine_Anhydrous + Betaine_Anhydrous + Taurine + Creatine_HCL + L_Theanine + L_Tyrosine + Sodium_Bicarbonate)* servings
#Servings Total
Serving_Total = float(L_Citrulline_Mallate + Beta_Alanine + Caffeine_Anhydrous + Betaine_Anhydrous + Taurine + Creatine_HCL + L_Theanine + L_Tyrosine + Sodium_Bicarbonate)
#Flavor
Flavor_Weight = float(Serving_Total/.8)
Flavor_Weight_Total = float(Flavor_Weight * servings)
Grand_Serving_Total_Weight = float(Flavor_Weight + Serving_Total)
Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)
#while
while (Grand_Weight_Mix_Total > 450):
        servings = servings - 1
        if Grand_Serving_Total_Weight <= 449:
                break
        print('Servings loop value', servings)
#Print 
print (f'Customer: {customerName}')
print (f'Mix Name: {mixName}')
print (f'Servings: {servings}')
print (f'L-Citrulline Malate: {L_Citrulline_Mallate}')
print (f'Beta Alanine: {Beta_Alanine}')
print (f'Caffeine Anhydrous: {Caffeine_Anhydrous}')
print (f'Betaine Anhydrous: {Betaine_Anhydrous}')
print (f'Taurine: {Taurine}')
print (f'Creatine HCL: {Creatine_HCL}')
print (f'L-Theanine: {L_Theanine}')
print (f'L-Tryosine: {L_Tyrosine}')
print (f'Sodium Bicarbonate: {Sodium_Bicarbonate}')
#Calculate total grams needed for each ingredent
Total_L_Citrulline_Mallate = int(L_Citrulline_Mallate * servings)
Total_Beta_Alanine = int(Beta_Alanine * servings)
Total_Caffeine_Anhydrous = float(Caffeine_Anhydrous * servings)
Total_Betaine_Anhydrous = int(Betaine_Anhydrous * servings)
Total_Taurine = int(Taurine * servings)
Total_Creatine_HCL = int(Creatine_HCL * servings)
Total_L_Theanine = float(L_Theanine * servings)
Total_L_Tyrosine = int(L_Tyrosine * servings)
Total_Sodium_Bicarbonate = float(Sodium_Bicarbonate * servings)
#Print total grams of each ingredient
print("L-Citrulline Mallate Total Grams:", Total_L_Citrulline_Mallate)
print("Beta Alanine Total Grams:", Total_Beta_Alanine)
print("Caffeine Anhydrous Total Grams:", Total_Caffeine_Anhydrous)
print("Betaine Anhydrous Total Grams:", Total_Betaine_Anhydrous)
print("Taurine Total Grams:", Total_Taurine)
print("Creatine HCL Total Grams:", Total_Creatine_HCL)
print("L-Theanine Total Grams:", Total_L_Theanine)
print("L-Tyrosine Total Grams:", Total_L_Tyrosine)
print("Sodium Bicarbonate Total Grams:", Total_Sodium_Bicarbonate)
print("Mix serving weight (flavor not included): ", Serving_Total)
print("Mix total wight: ", Mix_Total)
print("Flavor Weight", Flavor_Weight)
print("Flavor Weight Total", Flavor_Weight_Total)
print("Grand Total Serving Weight", Grand_Serving_Total_Weight)
print("Grand Total Mix Weight", Grand_Weight_Mix_Total)
```

Comment: Your `while` statement seems ok, but you never change `Grand_Weight_Mix_Total` within the loop, so it will loop forever.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't understand this line:

```py
Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)
```

This line mean that `Grand_Weight_Mix_Total` is the multiply of `Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings` in this moment, and it gonna stay like this until you change `Grand_Serving_Total_Weight` again

It's not getting updated when you change `servings`, you need to reassign the value your self by:

```py
while (Grand_Weight_Mix_Total > 450):
        servings = servings - 1
        Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)
        print('Servings loop value', servings)
```

also notice that i remove this

```py
if Grand_Serving_Total_Weight <= 449:
     break
```

which is redudent because of the while loop